# IP-CONFIG: no response | eth0 hardware address DHCP RARP

Tags: networking, debian, virtual-machines, xenserver, static-ip

I have debian 10 in a xenserver 7.0 vm with static ip and keeps trying dhcp. Already removed some packages that could be interfering, but must still have something installed.

[the post initialization image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ylgS.png)

EDIT:
I upgraded from debian 9.13 to debian 10. At first a normal upgrade. The disks are provisioned by xenserver.

Comment: Exactly how did you install Debian? How is the storage configured?

Comment: edited the post for more info

Comment: It looks like Debian is trying to do a diskless boot. This does appear to require DHCP. Check your domU configuration if this isn't what you expected.